# React Render Issue

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a simple application consisting of 4 components - most of it is working fine except one.

4 components

SearchContainer.js – has the search button and text box- on handle submit fetches the data based on search term and then renders item component. This works fine

Item.js – displays a list of items per search term and a link “product Detail” to get details of the specific item – works fine

ProductDetail.js – renders the specifications of item – and a link to the Compare Item- works fine – The compare card is a react router set up to render the compare card component which will get different merchant prices

CompareCard.js – This is where I have a problem
a)  The fetch/set state is failing – the state.product_compare is not being populated- what is odd is that the same api is populating data if I move the whole fetch code to the product detail component.
b)  Even though I had a dummy text in the render of comparecard component nothing is being rendered- I put a console.log inside the render and I can see the message- however it does not render anything. I can also see the prop is being passed corrected to the compare card component because I console.logedd it.
c)  Is it a problem with the way the router is invoked ? Why is the same api working in the other component but not this one? Why is nothing being rendered?

what is odd is that the same api is populating data if I move the whole fetch code to the product detail component.

Below is the actual code for the Product Detail and Comparecard components

ProductDetail.js ( renders the CompareCard via React Route)

```
import React from "react";
//import { Button} from 'reactstrap';
import { Link, Route, Router, HashRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import CompareCard from "./CompareCard";

const priceYugeAPI_KEY = "priceYugeAPI_KEY";
class ProductDetail extends React.Component {
  state = {
    product_details: []
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("In Product Detail", this.state.product_details);
    fetch(
      "https://price-api.datayuge.com/api/v1/compare/specs?" +
        `api_key=${priceYugeAPI_KEY}&id=${this.props.product_id}`
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      // console.log(response.json())
      .then(jsonResp =>
        this.setState({ product_details: jsonResp.data.main_specs })
      );
  }

  render() {
    console.log("product_detail", this.state.product_details);

    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          <HashRouter>
            <p>
              <Link
                to={`/compare/${this.props.product_id}`}
                component={CompareCard}
              >
                {" "}
                Compare Card{" "}
              </Link>
            </p>
            <Route
              exact
              path={`/compare/${this.props.product_id}`}
              render={() => <CompareCard product_id={this.props.product_id} />}
            />
            <div>
              <th>Main Specs </th>
            </div>
          </HashRouter>

          {this.state.product_details.map((product_detail, index) => (
            <tr>
              <td>{product_detail}</td>
              <p> &nbsp;</p>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default ProductDetail;
```

Comparecard.js ( Problem Component)

```
import React from "react";
const priceYugeAPI_KEY = "priceYugeAPI_KEY";

class CompareCard extends React.Component {
  state = {
    product_compare: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("inside did mount");
    console.log("prop", this.props.product_id);
    fetch(
      "https://price-api.datayuge.com/api/v1/compare/detail?" +
        `api_key=${priceYugeAPI_KEY}&id=${this.props.product_id}`
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(
        jsonResp => this.setState({ product_compare: jsonResp.data.stores }),
        error => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      );
    console.log("product_compare", this.state.product_compare);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          <th> Testbbbbbbbbbb {this.props.product_id}</th>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CompareCard;
```

I need Render  the data for diff merchants in the `CompareCard` component

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your state isn't being updated?

Here, you are calling console.log before your api call has completed:

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log("inside did mount");
    console.log("prop", this.props.product_id);
    fetch(
      "https://price-api.datayuge.com/api/v1/compare/detail?" +
        `api_key=${priceYugeAPI_KEY}&id=${this.props.product_id}`
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(
        jsonResp => this.setState({ product_compare: jsonResp.data.stores }),
        error => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      );
    // state hasn't been updated yet, fetch is async!
    console.log("product_compare", this.state.product_compare);
  }
```

Nothing in the `render()` of your `<CompareCard>` refers to `product_compare` from the state. If you move your console.log there, you should see that it is being updated after all.

```
  render() {
    console.log("product_compare", this.state.product_compare);
    return (
      <div>
      <table>
        <th>  Testbbbbbbbbbb {this.props.product_id}</th>
      </table>
      </div>

    )
```

Comment: Thanks- will add - but why is render not displaying the text "Test....."  and product_id - i can see the product_id in the console.log - Nothing is being rendered

Comment: sorry, hard to say without seeing the full code - suggest you try re-creating it in codesandbox

Comment: i tried the console.log inside the return- same issue- However, I sort of resolved the issue by moving the Router out to the parent- it seems to working- now I dont understand why the render did notw ork earlier with the router inside the product details- whenim ovde it to the parent it seems to be rendeing fine- Thanks for your hep